# Warning shown in logging MarkLogic : Clearing expired DatabaseQueryPath MarkLogic

Tags: warnings, marklogic, logfile, marklogic-dhf

After searching the internet via Google, we could not find any proper answer to our question. This is our situation...

We experience some warnings in the Windows Eventlog that shows this (Warning) information:

> Clearing expired DatabaseQueryPath 5845128627522525605, database=Security, timeLimit=598, expired=2019-01-18T12:41:00, started=2019-01-18T12:31:02

Can anyone explain what this warning information means ?

Comment: Can you find the corresponding entry in the MarkLogic error log and confirm it's a warning? It's possible this is simply an "info" message that appears as a warning in the Windows log.

Answer (score 1):

It means something like: some d-node work was going on, and it reached its time limit and had to be cleared by the server.  You might be able to correlate to some timeout error that happened at about the expired time, but on an e-node.